# Bootstrap 4 : Put text to the left of a button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons on top of each other. I'm trying to add some text on the left of the bottom one but I face 2 problems:

- The first one: It creates a white round-ish shape around my top button when I add the text
- The second one: I'm trying to find a clean way to put the text on the left of the button but can't figure out which way to use (flex?)

Here's my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKVwLG

Heres' what I want: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUdO6.png)

```
z
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Check this pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLmKre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SofiaChaves you are right but to achieve the goal of OP you need use some other property of `flexbox`

```css
.blockElement {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPVKLJ

Answer (score 2):

You can achive that by using flexbox.
Using "display:flex" everything goes side by side.
You have more information here (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about flexbox. It is pretty useful!

Solution:

```
<div style="display:flex">
   <span>some text</span>
   <button>Button1</button>
</div>
```

Here is the solution on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBYbgj